# Spring mongo slice array in embedded document

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongodb, mongotemplate

The slice method in aggreation for array within an embedded document is not working for me using spring mongo template.

Example:

**Invoice collection:**

```
{
  "reference_number": "aaa111",
  "historical_data": {
    "year": 2010,
    "data": [
      {
        "item_name": "Apple",
        "price": 50
      },
      {
        "item_name": "Book",
        "price": 200
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Using mongoTemplate I would like to get only the historical data in slices.

For the arrays which needs to be sliced that appear directly under the root I had found a solution using aggregation 
Refer : [Spring mongo repository slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35886810/spring-mongo-repository-slice)

Applying a similar query for array in an embedded document returns an empty list even if there is data.

The query that I was trying was :

```
TypedAggregation<Invoice> agg = newAggregation(Invoice.class,
                match(where("reference_number").is(referenceNumber)),
                project.andExpression("historicalData.data").slice(limit, offset));
        AggregationResults<Invoice> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, Invoice.class, Invoice.class);
```

But this returns an ***empty list*** of data.

### Is there any other alternative way to get the sliced result for arrays within an embedded document?

**Invoice.java**

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "invoice")
public class Invoice {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    @Field("reference_number")
    private String referenceNumber = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

   @Valid
    @Field("historical_data")
    private HistoricalData historicalData = new HistoricalData();
}
```

**HistoricalData:**

```
@Data
public class HistoricalData {
    @NotEmpty
    @Field("year")
    private Intger year;
    @Valid
    @NotNull
    @Field("data")
    private List<InvoiceData> data = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

---

***Note :*** *I have also tried :*

```
TypedAggregation<Invoice> agg = newAggregation(Invoice.class,
                match(where("reference_number").is(referenceNumber)),
                project.andExpression("historical_data.data").slice(limit, offset));
        AggregationResults<Invoice> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, Invoice.class, Invoice.class);
```

But this gave me a PropertyPathException.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a weeks struggle I have figured out a solution for this:

```
ProjectionOperation project = project().and("historicalRevisionData.data").slice(limit, offset).as("historical_revision_data.data")
                .andInclude("id")
                .and("referenceNumber").as("reference_number");
TypedAggregation<Invoice> agg = newAggregation(Invoice.class,
                match(where("reference_number").is(referenceNumber)),
                project);
AggregationResults<TaxInvoice> aggregate = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, Invoice.class, Invoice.class);
```

Hoping that this would help someone else too.

Comment: Could you please guide me here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55532310/find-distinct-embedded-documents-from-the-document-using-spring-data-mongo?